# Nextjs 10 .process.env.local variables undefined

Tags: next.js

I am getting undefined from my .env.local using Next 10

As per the docs in my .env.local I have

```
TEST='test'
```

and in the main code I am trying to access this using

```
console.log(process.env.local.TEST)
```

But it is coming back undefined. I have rebuilt after each change to files but still undefined.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be `process.env.TEST`, without local